# Any basic paper on biomedical signal processing to practise with?

Tags: matlab, signal-analysis, signal-detection

I am quite interested in biomedical signal processing and I am looking for some biomedical signal processing papers in order to reproduce the results that they obtained. The idea is to redo what they did so I can learn about the topic and improve my research skills.

The papers should fit the following requisites:

- The data that they use must be public.
- Most of the work could be done in Matlab or similar software.

Papers about biomedical image processing are also welcomed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have enough reputation to comment... You can use
[Physionet](http://physionet.org/). Through it you have access to physiological databases and software kits for data analysis. The software tools are programmed in MATLAB. Relevant papers can be found in the software documentation or in the Physionet library under publications. Also, it's free.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you go to [PLOS Biology](http://journals.plos.org/plosbiology/) and do a search for "Signaling MatLab".  There are many scientific papers there on various biology research topics.  Some even give the Matlab commands used.